# Solr fuzzy search problem for some tokens

Tags: solr, lucene, fuzzy-search

Enviornment- java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS, solr-8.9.0

I have the following field declaration for my Solr index:

```
<field name="author" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Field type:

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I understand that "Lucene supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or Edit Distance algorithm. To do a
fuzzy search the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of a Single word Term is used.

~ operator is used to run fuzzy searches. We need to add ~ operator after every single term and can also specify
distance which is optional after that as below."

```
{FIELD_NAME:TERM_1~{Edit_Distance}
```

My request looks like below.

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select --data-urlencode "q=(author:Harol~)"
```

Since 'KeywordTokenizer' keeps the whole input as a single token and I want each word to be searchable, so
'StandardTokenizer' is used.

My request is running correctly for following input

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select --data-urlencode "q=(author:Harol~)" --data-urlencode "rows=2"

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"author:Harol~",
      "rows":"2"}},
  "response":{"numFound":939,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "Field1":"1",
        "author":"Haxyol",
        "Field2":"jfkdl",            
        "_version_":1744603055722070016},
      {
        "Field1":"24583728576090850",
        "author":"Hastol",
        "Field2":"dfafi fdhee fddfd",            
        "_version_":1744602582382280721}]
  }}
```

but not running for the following input

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select --data-urlencode "q=(author:pinter~)" --data-urlencode "rows=2"

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"author:pinter~",
      "rows":"2"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3780,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "Field1":"2",
        "author":"pinter",
        "Field2":"jfdfakdl",            
        "_version_":1744603055722070016},
      {
        "Field1":"2458372850",
        "author":"pinter",
        "Field2":"afdfih hefdad afdsaf",
        
        "_version_":1744602582382280721}]
  }}
```

Although there is one author 'piopter' indexed in solr,but it was not in the result of above query, This was verified by
running following query.

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select --data-urlencode "q=(author:piopter)" --data-urlencode "rows=2"

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"author:piopter",
      "rows":"2"}},
  "response":{"numFound":892,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "Field1":"3",
        "author":"piopter",
        "Field2":"fadfjfdfakdl",            
        "_version_":1744603055722070016},
      {
        "Field1":"24dfda58372850",
        "author":"piopter",
        "Field2":"fdsfafdfi hefda afddsaf",            
        "_version_":1744602582382280721}]
  }}
```

why 'piopter' is not result for input '**pinter**~' but 'Haxyol' is result of 'Harol~'.
Observation is, there are **939** reocrds for Harol~ and **3780** reords for pinter~. Total index document present in solr are 1.6
milion records.

so I tried to post everything you need to understand my problem. Any ideas?
Any parameters need to configure in solrconfig.xml like threshold, maxResult ?

Comment: How did you determine that `piopter` wasn't in the result set for your first query? You get `"numFound":3780` and only look at the two first ones? `piopter` could be any of those other 3778 documents?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your reply! I have parsed the complete result-set, 'piopter' was not present.  I am pretty sure,'piopter' token is not present in the result-set. Is it related to some configuration of 'solr-config.xml'?

Comment: You might want to use the `explainOther` option in your query and pass the ID of the document that you expect to come in the results and see how Solr is handling it: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/common-query-parameters.html#explainother-parameter

Comment: @Hector Correa ... Thankx for reply! As per 'explainOther' info "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)\n 0.0 = no match on required clause"....What can be the possible reason? Note:'Field1' is uniqueKey instead of 'id'...............TestCase - I have deleted all documents of 'piopter' in solr and than inserted few records of 'piopter', Now input 'pinter' is successfully producing output as 'piopter'. Why it is not working for larger number of documents or indexes?

Comment: Kindly download the .csv file 'drive.google.com/file/d/1z684x2GKsSQWGAdyi6O4uKit4a96iiuh/view' and after indexing run commands ........ 1. curl "localhost:8983/solr/EditDistance2Problem/select" --data-urlencode "q=Field1:w1" ............ 2.curl "localhost:8983/solr/EditDistance2Problem/select" --data-urlencode "q=author:beaeb~' AND Field1:w1"

Comment: Kindly reply...

Answer (score 0):

> I have deleted all documents of 'piopter' in solr and than inserted
> few records of 'piopter', Now input 'pinter' is successfully producing
> output as 'piopter'. Why it is not working for larger number of
> documents or indexes?

Is it possible that you changed your schema but did not reindex those documents?

Comment: ...Thankx for reply, But I haven't changed the schema.

Answer (score 0):

The edit distance from **pinter** to **piopter** is **2**. High edit distances will result in a poor scoring, so pioter will be at the very end of your 3780 matches. If our dataset consists of 1.6M documents, there will be many better matches to pinter~. Fuzzy searches on large datasets with edit distances above 1 usually produce a lot of noise.

My suggestions for further investigations:

- Set **rows=1000** (or higher) and see if you can find it there.
- Explicitly search for **pinter~2**. Maybe someone configured the default to 1.
- Try fuzzy searches closer to your target, e.g. **pinpter~1**

Comment: 1. I have analyzed the complete result-set of 3780 records, but  'piopter' was not present for input pinter~.... 2.pinter~2 also doesnt work .... 3. "closer to target" for input pinpter~ gives output successfully 'piopter'....but why 'piopter' is not in the output for input pinter~.....My observation : If i keep only few records of 'piopter' in solr than for input pinter~ is resulting output of 'piopter'.... Is it related to large number of indexes?

Comment: Ok.... next try: Use an additional filter query fq=(Field2:fadfjfdfakdl). This will drastically reduce the number of potential candidates. With this combination we can see if your query (q) would basically work. BTW, could you also add the result scores to your examples? They should be rather low with edit distance of 2.

Comment: Thankx for reply.. "filter query fq=(Field2:fadfjfdfakdl) along with q=*:* " is giving 
author:piopter~ .... "filter query fq=(Field2:fadfjfdfakdl)" is giving "numFound":0" for 
input pinter~..... Input query; pinter~ and score for the first document having author as 
'pinter is 7.139886 and score for the last document(3780th) having author as 'pintxy is 1.8256896 .. .As you can see pintxy having edit-distance as 2 is coming in output but not piopter...My obervation: There are lot of records for 'piopter' but only 2 records for 'pintxy ' Note:'Field1' is uniqueKey instead of 'id'

Comment: How many occurences of piopter do you have in your documents? The default scoring mechanism TF/IDF (do you use this?) produces lower scores for the most frequent tokens. As you say, that you get correct result when there are only a few documents in it, you may watch the score changing (lowering) when adding more and more documents with piopter. There might be a threshold when the token becomes almost irrelevant for the scoring, although this is not the default behaviour. A match is a match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 892 documents are present having the term 'piopter'.....There is no change in the scoring mechanism, it is running by default. Solr configuration is running on default.

Comment: There are also 3500 documents present having author:'pinter'.

Comment: 3500x pinter + 892x piopter => at least 4392 matches for your query. This means numFound=3780 is too low. But why? Are you sure all shards are ok? Is shards.tolerant=true?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  It is a standalone mode('solr core'-'single index') configuration, not a cluster (collection-external zookeeper ensemble) type of configuration.

Comment: Kindly download the .csv file 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z684x2GKsSQWGAdyi6O4uKit4a96iiuh/view' and after indexing run commands ........        1. curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/EditDistance2Problem/select" --data-urlencode "q=Field1:w1" ............
               2.curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/EditDistance2Problem/select" --data-urlencode "q=author:beaeb~' AND Field1:w1"